# How do I get this mock to work?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, moq

I need to make changes to a legacy class with no tests so I have started by writing a test, however the mocking (using Moq) isn't working properly.

This my test

```
[Test]
public void CorrectlyCopiesToLightningWhenNoLocationsExist()
{
  // arrange
  long orgId = Id64.NewId();
  var data = LightningMapLocationsHelperTestData.ForNormalCopy(orgId);

  var organisation = new Group
  {
    GroupId = orgId,
    Name = "Test Organisation",
    Type = GroupType.OrganisationGroup
  };

  var groupRepo = new Mock<IGroupRepository>();
  groupRepo.Setup(r => r.GetGroup(orgId)).Returns(organisation);

  var orgRepo = Mock.Of<IOrganisationRepository>(o => o.LightningLocationsEnabledFor(orgId));

  var mapLocationRepo = new Mock<IMapLocationRepository>();
  mapLocationRepo.Setup(r => r.OrganisationRepository).Returns(orgRepo);
  mapLocationRepo
    .Setup(r => r.GetMapLocationsByGroupIds(orgId, It.IsAny<IEnumerable<long>>(), true, true))
    .Returns(data.InitialDatabaseLocations);

  var lightningMapLocationRepo = new Mock<ILightningMapLocationRepository>();
  lightningMapLocationRepo
    .Setup(r => r.LocationsById(orgId, data.InitialLightningLocations.Select(l => l.LocationId)))
    .Returns(data.InitialLightningLocations);
  lightningMapLocationRepo
    .Setup(r => r.AddLocations(It.IsAny<List<Location>>()))
    .Callback((List<Location> locations) => data.InitialLightningLocations.AddRange(locations));

  var infoMessages = new List<string>();
  var errorMessages = new List<string>();

  var helper = new LightningMapLocationsHelper(
    (string s, object[] args) => infoMessages.Add(string.Format(s, args)),
    (string s, object[] args) => errorMessages.Add(string.Format(s, args)));

  List<CopyFailure> copyFailures;

  // act
  bool success = helper.CopyLocationsForOrganisation(orgId, 10, out copyFailures);

  // assert
  success.ShouldBeTrue();
  (errorMessages?.Count ?? 0).ShouldBe(0);
  data.InitialLightningLocations.Count.ShouldBe(data.ExpectedLightningLocations.Count);
}
```

Inside `LightningMapLocationsHelper` is the following method

```
private Group GetValidOrganisationGroup(long groupId)
{
  var organisation = (new GroupRepository()).GetGroup(groupId);
  if (organisation != null && organisation.Type == GroupType.OrganisationGroup) return organisation;

  LogErrorMessage("Invalid groupId: {0}. Ignoring...", groupId);
  return null;
}
```

that when called is using an actual instance of `GroupRepository` rather than the `groupRepo` mock set up in the test, thus causing the test to fail. As `GroupRepository` implements `IGroupRepository` I expected this to work.

```
public class GroupRepository : IGroupRepository {…}
```

Perhaps I am misunderstanding how mocking works. Can someone offer some insight to help me understand why this doesn't work, and how I can fix it? Do I have to pass the mocked classes in?

Comment: You may need to post your LightningMapLocationHelper out but looks like you didn't pass any of the mock object into the helper. How would you expect those mocks to work ?

Comment: i assume your LightningMapLocationHelper havs ILightningMapLocationRepository, IMapLocationRepository, IOrganisationRepository, IGroupRepository as references in it ?

Comment: As I said I don't fully understand mocking. I guess I thought there was some magic behind the scenes that linked up the mocks. Now you have pointed out that this isn't the case, I will refactor my helper so that dependencies (or mocks) are passed in.

Comment: Nar. the most common mock Rhino & MOQ don't provide reference override.  I guess an indirect way for doing what you want is using MEF to create your Repositories and then put your mocks to CompositionContainer. That's a way you don't need to modify your helper class constructor and get mock obj in

Comment: I don't want to add MEF as all our tests use only Moq so I prefer not to add something else just to facilitate testing.

Comment: Old-school way it is then. We're in the same club actually. Still not buying things like MEF yet. Always produces messy result if it's in wrong hand. Hardcore injection by constructor or using factory normal can keep people in check.

Comment: Old-school is right. I've been a dev for 30 years and think my brain is full; I struggle to grasp some new concepts. Looked at MEF when it first came out and found it not too easy to comprehend, and since nobody else here is using it, that's where it ended.